# Initializing variable in try catch block

Tags: java

I am getting the error in Java:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem
>       The local variable b1 may not have been initialized at Test.main(Test.java:20)

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.String;
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char a[]={'s','k'};
        String s0=new String(a);
        String s1=new String("Amar");
        String s2= "amarnath";
        byte[] b1;
        try{
         b1=s2.getBytes("ASCII");
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        for(int i =0;i<s2.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(b1[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: consider moving `for(...)` inside `try` after `b1 = ... ` to print array contents only if it is successfully initialized. Now, if `b1` is not assigned due to exception, it is not initialized when entering `for()`--thus you're getting this error.

Comment: Don’t swallow exceptions.It’s not only good general advice, I think it will also solve your concrete problem.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou  thanks .. it worked..  But can you tell why my code is having the problem. Is this due to the try scope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `getBytes(String encoding)` throws `UnsupportedEncodingException`. If such an exception occurs in your code (this will happen if you put wrong encoding for example `getBytes("foo")`), your byte array will remain uninitialized. The catch block will handle the exception and continue with the for loop where you are trying to use b1. The compiler sees that possibility and throws an error in order to prevent usage of uninitialized variable later.

```java
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char a[]={'s','k'};
        String s0=new String(a);
        String s1=new String("Amar");
        String s2= "amarnath";
        byte[] b1;
        try{
         b1=s2.getBytes("ASCII");
         for(int i =0;i<s2.length();i++)
         {
            System.out.println(b1[i]);
         }
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee){ 
            //handle the exception or at least log it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM**

If there is an error inside the `try` block, then `b1` would not have been initialized and would have a value of `null`.

If this happens, then there would be a problem when you try and print out `b1`'s values in the following line:

```
System.out.println(b1[i]);
```

Java is cautious and won't let the possibility of that happen.

---

**SOLUTIONS**

1. Initialize `b1` with a default value

   - This will prevent the possibility that `b1` is uninitialized (which is what Java worried about)
2. Put the `for` loop inside the `try` block (as @SashaSalauyou said in the comments)

   - If there is an error with `b1`'s inialization in the `try` block, then the block will quit, and the `for` loop would not be run. Therefore, there would be no code using the uninitialized variable such as in aforementioned line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because if the `b1` is not initialized and if *something bad* happens inside the `try` block, it will be then used in the following block, `System.out.println(b1[i]);`, uninitialized.

In order to make it compile, you should initialize your variable at least with `null`, as it is local variable.